# Error: 'React' must be in scope when using JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Making a test project with React on debian 10 with VScode on Windows 8.1, when using the command `yarn start` in project folder, then an error comes out:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 6:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 7:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 8:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 9:    'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 10:  'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
  Line 12:   'React' must be in scope when using JSX  react/react-in-jsx-scope
```

solutions with `import React from 'react';` or `"react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"` is didnt work. What else could be the problem?

Comment: `import React from 'react';` should absolutely get rid of this error. (Which I assume occurs because you're using React 16 or earlier.) Please show us your App.js including this import, and what error you get when running that (assuming it's different from the above, which it certainly should be).

Comment: Maybe I am missing somthing, or maybe your using WSL. But I don't get how your creating a React program in Debian on windows 8.1 (it has to be WSL right?) if so you should state that, if not, please clarify.

Comment: @J-D3V I'm not sure if it is because you are using WSL.  I am using windows and still getting the same error (React 18.0.2). And I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3):

1. Added in the beginning part of js file.

import React from 'react'

This will resolve the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: problem solved
i just updated yarn and nodeJS

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, it got solved by running npm audit fix --force.
I would try reinstalling the packages.